# Should I use dynamic cast in the subject observer pattern with templates

Tags: c++, design-patterns

By referring to article [Implementing a Subject/Observer pattern with templates](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/architecture/observer_with_templates.aspx)

```
template <class T>
class Observer
   {
   public:
      Observer() {}
      virtual ~Observer() {}
      virtual void update(T *subject)= 0;
   };

template <class T>
class Subject
   {
   public:
      Subject() {}
      virtual ~Subject() {}
      void attach (Observer<T> &observer)
         {
         m_observers.push_back(&observer);
         }
      void notify ()
         {
         std::vector<Observer<T> *>::iterator it;
         for (it=m_observers.begin();it!=m_observers.end();it++) 
              (*it)->update(static_cast<T *>(this));
         }
   private:
      std::vector<Observer<T> *> m_observers;
   };
```

I was wondering instead of `static_cast`, shall I use `dynamic_cast`?

This is because if I am using `static_cast`, I will get compilation error in the following case.

```
class Zoo : public Observer<Animal> {
public:
    Zoo() {
        animal = new Bird();
        animal->attach(this);
    }

    virtual ~Zoo() {
    delete animal;
    }

    virtual void update(Animal* subject) {
    }

    Animal* animal;
}

// If using static_cast, compilation error will happen here.
class Bird : public Animal, public Subject<Animal> {
public:
    virtual ~Bird() {
    }
}
```

Is there any side effect of using `dynamic_cast`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best would surely be not to have to cast at all. You could change your `notify()` function so that it takes the right argument:

```
  void notify (T* obj)
     {
     std::vector<Observer<T> *>::iterator it;
     for (it=m_observers.begin();it!=m_observers.end();it++) 
          (*it)->update(obj);
     }
```

Now derived classes can pass the right object (`this`, if appropriate) without the base class needing to know the relation of derived classes to `T`.

---

Looking at your code as it is, that `static_cast` relies on the fact that whatever derives from `Observer`, will also derive from whatever it passes as a template argument. I think if this wouldn't hold, it would be caught at compile-time, because you couldn't `static_cast` from `this` to `T*`.

However, your code is very close to a pattern known as the Curiously Recurring Template Pattern. For it to fit perfectly, pass the derived class' type to `Observer`:

```
class Bird : public Subject<Bird> // note the template argument
```

Now you don't need to derive from `Observer`'s `T` anymore and whoever looks at it (hopefully) recognizes the pattern and understands the code more easily.

Answer (score 2):

On a tangential line of reasoning, you can use existing libraries for this, like `boost::signal` that let you define an *event* and connect *listeners* (observers) to that event.

```
// Forgive the lack of encapsulation and const-correctness to keep the example simple:
struct Animal {
   boost::signal< void ( Animal& )> signal_update;
   std::string name;
};
class Bird : public Animal {
public:
   void rename( std::string const & n ) { 
      name = n;
      signal_update(*this);
   }
};
class Zoo
{
public:
   Zoo() : bird() {
      bird.signal_update.connect( boost::bind( &Zoo::an_animal_changed, this, _1 ) );
   }
   void an_animal_changed( Animal & a ) {
      std::cout << "New name is " << a.name << std::endl;
   }
   Bird bird;
};
int main() {
   Zoo zoo;
   zoo.bird.rename( "Tweety" ); // New name is Tweety
}
```

The advantage (and disadvantage) of this solution is that it loosens the coupling between the observer and the subject. This means that you cannot enforce that only `Zoo`s can observe animals, or that the method used for *observing* has a concrete signature/name. This is at the same time an advantage if your `Animal` does not know or care who is observing:

```
class Scientist {
public:
   Scientist( Zoo & zoo )
   {
      zoo.bird.signal_update.connect( boost::bind( &Scientist::study, this, _1 ) );
   }
   void study( Animal & a ) {
      std::cout << "Interesting specimen this " << a.name << std::endl;
   }
};
int main() {
   Zoo zoo;
   Scientist pete(zoo);
   zoo.bird.rename( "Tweety" ); // New name is: Tweety
                                // Interesting specimen this Tweety
}
```

Note that both the type and function name can be adapted by `boost::bind`. If a scientist works in two zoos, it could even be notified of which zoo the animal changing belongs to:

```
// [skipped]: added a name to the zoo
void Scientist::work_at( Zoo & zoo ) {
   zoo.bird.signal_update.connect( boost::bind( &Scientist::study, this, _1, zoo.name ) );
}
// updated signature:
void Scientist::study( Animal & a, std::string const & zoo_name )
{
   std::cout << "Interesting animal " << a.name << " in zoo " << zoo_name << std::endl;
}
```