# Template based Subject Observer pattern - Should I use static_cast or dynamic_cast

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I am referring to the article [Implementing a Subject/Observer pattern with templates](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/architecture/observer_with_templates.aspx)

I did some modification and it became code as follow.

```
template <class T, class A>
class Observer {
public:
    Observer() {}
    virtual ~Observer() {}
    virtual void update(T& subject, A arg) = 0;
};

template <class T, class A>
class Subject
{
public:
    Subject() {}
    virtual ~Subject() {}

    // Take note that, we didn't make the following functions as virtual,
    // as we do not expect them to be overridden.
    void attach(Observer<T, A> &observer) {
        // Ensure no duplication.
        std::vector<Observer<T, A> *>::const_iterator iterator = std::find(observers.begin(), observers.end(), &observer);
        if (iterator == observers.end()) {
            observers.push_back(&observer);
        }
    }

    void dettach(Observer<T, A> &observer) {
        std::vector<Observer<T, A> *>::const_iterator iterator = std::find(observers.begin(), observers.end(), &observer);
        if (iterator != observers.end()) {
            observers.erase(iterator);
        }
    }

    void dettachAll() {
        observers.clear();
    }

    void notify(A arg)
    {
        std::vector<Observer<T, A> *>::const_iterator it;
        for (it = observers.begin(); it != observers.end(); it++) { 
            (*it)->update(*(static_cast<T *>(this)), arg);
        }
    }

private:
    std::vector<Observer<T, A> *> observers;
};
```

Later, I realize that `(*it)->update(*(static_cast<T *>(this)), arg);` is having limitation. For example,

```
// cause compilation error in static_cast, as it cannot cast cat1 to animal.
class cat1 : public animal, public Subject<animal, int> {
public:
    virtual void speak() {
        notify(888);
    }
};

class zoo1 : public Observer<animal, int> {
public:
    zoo1() {
        c.attach(*this);
        c.speak();
    }

    virtual void update(animal& subject, int arg) {
        cout << "zoo1 received notification " << arg << endl;
    }

    cat1 c;
};
```

I can solve the problem by changing the `static_cast` to `dynamic_cast`. **However, I am not sure whether I will fall into other traps?** My guess on author original intention in having `static_cast`, is to ensure type safety checking during compile time.

Comment: This appears to be answered here: [Should I use dynamic cast in the subject observer pattern with templates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975624/should-i-use-dynamic-cast-in-the-subject-observer-pattern-with-templates)

Answer (score 2):

Your problem come from the fact that animal should be the subject not only the cat,

```
class animal : public Subject<animal,int>
{
    ...
};

class cat1 : public animal
{
    public:
    virtual void speak() 
    {
        notify(888);
    }
};

class zoo1 : public Observer<animal, int> {
public:
    zoo1() 
    {
        c.attach(*this);
        c.speak();
    }

virtual void update(animal& subject, int arg) 
    {
        cout << "zoo1 received notification " << arg << endl;
    }

cat1 c;
};
```

By doing this every Subject are static-cast "able" to animal. This is not the case with your cat1

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Cyrs, in your example, the compiler tries to `static_cast` a `Subject<animal, int>*` into an `animal*` whereas neither `animal` nor `Subject<animal, int>` inherits the other one, even indirectly. The compiler considers this conversion as impossible.

If you replace `static_cast` by `dynamic_cast`, it will be evaluated at runtime if this conversion is possible. In your example, it is, because `cat1` is luckily both an `animal` and an `Observer<animal, int>`. So it will always work with `dynamic_cast` if the user (developer) doesn't do any mistake, i.e. if he/she provides classes with this kind of hierarchy.

So you may want to make your implementation with `dynamic_cast` more robust and detect programming mistakes. With such a mistake, `dynamic_cast` will return a null pointer. So you could test if `dynamic_cast` returns a null pointer either in `notify()`, in `attach()` or in `Subject()`, and avoid using the pointer in that case.

Note that `dynamic_cast` is less efficient than `static_cast` because of runtime type evaluations.

I would rather go for Cyrs' solution.

As pointed out in a comment, you should also consider the accepted answer of following thread: [Should I use dynamic cast in the subject observer pattern with templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975624/should-i-use-dynamic-cast-in-the-subject-observer-pattern-with-templates/), which is a nice alternative.