# C++ error: invalid conversion from (base class template) to subclass

Tags: c++

I have been using the Subject-Observer pattern with success in a project.  As the number of Subject-Observer and message types has grown to 5+, I find myself duplicating the same code pattern for each.  I am trying to switch to a class template for the Subject-Observer pattern.  But I am stuck on a compiler error I have been unable to resolve (despite efforts):

```
Building file: ../main.cpp
Invoking: GCC C++ Compiler
g++ -std=c++0x -O3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -MMD -MP -MF"main.d" -MT"main.d" -o "main.o" "../main.cpp"
../main.cpp: In instantiation of ‘Observer<T_subject, T_message>::~Observer() [with T_subject = RotationSubject; T_message = long unsigned int]’:
../main.cpp:49:7:   required from here
../main.cpp:39:15: error: invalid conversion from ‘Observer<RotationSubject, long unsigned int>* const’ to ‘RotationObserver*’ [-fpermissive]
  ~Observer(){ subject->UnregisterObserver( this ); }
           ^
../main.cpp:10:7: error:   initializing argument 1 of ‘void Subject<T_observer, T_message>::UnregisterObserver(T_observer*) [with T_observer = RotationObserver; T_message = long unsigned int]’ [-fpermissive]
  void UnregisterObserver(  T_observer*  observer ){
   ^
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
```

Minimal working example code is:

```
#include <vector>

template <class T_observer, typename T_message> class Subject
{
public:
void RegisterObserver( T_observer* observer ){
    observers.push_back(observer);
}

void UnregisterObserver(  T_observer*  observer ){
    for (auto itr = begin(observers); itr != end(observers); itr++){
        if (*itr == observer){
            itr = observers.erase(itr);
            if (itr == observers.end()) break;
        }
    }
}

void NotifyObservers( T_message message ){
    for(auto const& itr : observers){
        itr->ReceiveMessage( message );
    }
}

std::vector < T_observer * > observers;
};


template <class T_subject, typename T_message> class Observer
{
public:

Observer( T_subject* subject )
: subject( subject )
{
    subject->RegisterObserver( this );
}

~Observer(){ subject->UnregisterObserver( this ); }

virtual void ReceiveMessage( T_message message ) {};
// Observer sub-classes define ReceiveMessage

T_subject* subject;
};

class RotationSubject;// forward declaration prevents circular dependency

class RotationObserver : public Observer< RotationSubject, unsigned long>
{
public:
RotationObserver( RotationSubject* rotation_subject );
};

class RotationSubject : public Subject< RotationObserver, unsigned long>
{ };

int main(int argc, char * argv[]){
RotationSubject* pRotSubject = new RotationSubject( );
RotationObserver* pRotObserver = new RotationObserver( pRotSubject );
pRotObserver->~RotationObserver();
return 0;
}
```

The intention is to define subclasses which derive from these base class templates, as shown here with `RotationSubject` and `RotationObserver`.  The motivation for the type identifiers `T_observer` and `T_subject` is to be specific about which subclasses can be paired, e.g. `RotationObservers` should only observe `RotationSubjects`, and receive Rotation message types (`T_message` is `unsigned long` in this example).

If I read the error message correctly, `Observer<RotationSubject, long unsigned int>* const` is **not** a `RotationObserver*`, or the compiler is not aware of how to convert.

I explored circular dependency and const as the cause, without success.

Please help me to understand the cause of this error message, and if possible a minimal edit to correct.  This is my primary question.

I am open to completely different designs, and suggestions for improvement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Further searching turned up some helpful links specifically related to templating the Subject-Observer pattern:
(https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3267/Implementing-a-Subject-Observer-pattern-with-templ)
([Template based Subject Observer pattern - Should I use static_cast or dynamic_cast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4341693/template-based-subject-observer-pattern-should-i-use-static-cast-or-dynamic-ca))
([Should I use dynamic cast in the subject observer pattern with templates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3975624/should-i-use-dynamic-cast-in-the-subject-observer-pattern-with-templates))

The following code is a corrected version which works.  It was derived from the first link.  Per @BoundaryImposition 's answer, it uses `static_cast` in the templated Subject::NotifyObservers() method to obtain a pointer to the *Subject subclass*.  I'm not 100% comfortable with this concept, but it works.  The magic sauce, per my understanding, is the use of the [Curiously Recurring Template Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) in `Subject`. Specifically `class Temperature : public Subject<Temperature>` (second template identifier removed for clarity).  Whereas before I was using `class RotationSubject : public Subject<RotationObserver>`, which is a totally different inheritance.  The `Observer` subclass `PanicSiren` also has a different inheritance.

Note that my template moves `RegisterObserver` and `UnregisterObserver` to the `Observer` ctor and dtor.  Not required, just the way I like it.  I have also added the message type template identifier `T_message`, which allows for various message types.

I am pleased, as the intended design was achieved without a massive rewrite :).

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T_subject, typename T_message> class Observer{
public:
    Observer( T_subject* subject ) : subject(subject) { subject->RegisterObserver( *this ); }
    virtual ~Observer() { subject->UnregisterObserver( *this ); }
    virtual void ReceiveMessage( T_subject* subject, T_message message ) = 0;// =0 requires subclasses to define
    T_subject* subject;
};

template <class T_subject, class T_message> class Subject{
public:
    virtual ~Subject() {}
    void NotifyObservers( T_message message ){
        typename std::vector<Observer<T_subject,T_message> *>::iterator it;
        for ( it=m_observers.begin(); it!=m_observers.end(); ++it){
            T_subject* this_subject_subclass = static_cast<T_subject*>(this);// pointer to _subclass_ type, curiously not yet defined ;)
            (*it)->ReceiveMessage( this_subject_subclass, message );
        }
    }

    void RegisterObserver( Observer<T_subject,T_message> &observer ){
        m_observers.push_back( &observer ); }

    void UnregisterObserver( Observer<T_subject,T_message> &observer ){
        for (auto itr = begin(m_observers); itr != end(m_observers); itr++){
            if (*itr == &observer){
                itr = m_observers.erase(itr);
                if (itr == m_observers.end())   break;
            }
        }
    }
private:
    std::vector<Observer<T_subject,T_message> *> m_observers;
};

class Temperature : public Subject<Temperature,unsigned long> {};

class PanicSiren : public Observer<Temperature,unsigned long>
{
public:
    PanicSiren(Temperature* subject)
    : Observer<Temperature,unsigned long>::Observer(subject) {}
    void ReceiveMessage( Temperature *subject, unsigned long message ){
        std::cout << "Temperature changed to " << message <<", sounding the siren"
                << std::endl;
    }
};

int main(int argc, char * argv[]){
    Temperature* temp = new Temperature();
    PanicSiren* panic = new PanicSiren( temp );
    temp->NotifyObservers( 42 );
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're dropping a `const` qualifier. You can't do that without a `const_cast` and a good reason.

You're also trying to convert in the "wrong" direction. Not every `Observer< RotationSubject, unsigned long>` is necessarily a `RotationObserver`, although the reverse is true. You can make it work with a `dynamic_cast` (or with a `static_cast` and a promise).

Comment: Thank you for answer :)  You correctly identified both the issues; inheritance and type casting.  The `static_cast` was an easy addition, but correcting the inheritance pattern took a bit more reading.

Comment: @TysonHilmer: Glad you got it!